# Override Android drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I would like to override the built-in `@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame` as I want to make a few adjustments such as change the `<solid>` color among other things. However when I go to declaration it takes me here:

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="dialog_holo_dark_frame">@drawable/dialog_full_holo_dark</drawable>
```

And when I try to go to declaration there it `Cannot find declaration to go to`. Therefore I can't see the source xml code for me to replicate + override.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Look in `$ANRDROID_SDK/platforms/$PLATFORM/data/res/drawable-$DENSITY/`, where:

- `$ANDROID_SDK` is where your Android SDK is installed
- `$PLATFORM` is some platform that you have downloaded (e.g., `android-28`)
- `$DENSITY` is some density (e.g., `-mdpi`)

Note, though, that `dialog_full_holo_dark` is a nine-patch PNG, not a `ShapeDrawable`.